# Is arbitrary union any different from typical union (set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So suppose that $\bigcup_{i}X_i \, i \in \mathbb{N}$ where $X_i = \{x \, \, | \, x \leq i, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$. So, $X_1 = \{0,1\}$ and so on. Question is, will this arbitrary union result in the following? $\bigcup_i X_i = \{\{0,1,2,3...\}\}$

Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When we write $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ we mean the set (or class): $$\{x\mid\exists i\in I: x\in X_i\}$$

That is all the elements which appear at least in one of the $X_i$'s. So in the case where $I=\mathbb N$ and $X_i=\{k\in\mathbb N\mid k\leq i\}$ we simply get $\mathbb N$, and not $\{\mathbb N\}$.

I should probably add that if $\cal A$ is a collection of sets then often we write $\bigcup\cal A$ instead of $\bigcup_{A\in\cal A}A$. But context is usually enough to discern between the two, moreover one lacks the index at the bottom.